# How to query CSV file using SQL language in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: sql, csv, visual-studio-code

I have data in `.CSV` and Excel files. I do not know if it is possible or not, but I need to manipulate these files using SQL. I am working in a very restrictive environment where I cannot install SQL Server and I cannot use web-based server due to data privacy. All I have is Visual Studio Code.

Is there any way to use SQL to query from `.CSV` file instead of SQL Server tables in VS Code, assuming the `.CSV` file as a local SQL table and running SQL using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: convert the CSV file to a sqlite database, and apply SQL to that in what ever tool you like, VSC might have a sqlite viewer extension, I don't know if it allows modifications

Comment: Each SQL dbms has its own storage format. Are you looking for a dbms that can access both Excel and csv files?

Answer (score 2):

For VS Code there is the [Rainbow CSV](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mechatroner.rainbow-csv) plug-in, which has `RBQL` an SQL-like query language.

Does it have to be VS Code? I mean Notepad++ has the [CsvQuery plug-in](https://github.com/jokedst/CsvQuery) which is pretty good.